# Expected value of function of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$, which is uniformly distributed between 0.68 and 0.72. I define a new variable $Y$ as $$Y=\sin(X)$$

and using the inverse formula to find the probability distribution function I get the new distribution function $$F_Y(y) = 33.33 y \sqrt{1-y^2}$$ which exists between 0.629 and 0.659. The problem is if I find the expected value of $Y$ using the normal integral I get a different value when I use the Law of the Unconcious Statistician on $g(X)$. Why is there this discrepancy? Am I not allowed to use the Unconcious Statistician in this case?

Comment: Can you please show the work that you have done here? Also, the LOTUS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) holds in general, so there shouldn't be a discrepancy.

Comment: How do you get that CDF? I get a PDF of $$f_Y(y) =\left\{\begin{array}{cc}  \frac{25}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} & \mbox{if $y \in I$} \\ 0 & \mbox{else}\end{array}\right. $$ where $I$ is an appropriate interval.